# Randomly Disappearing Text Effect - Selecting Random Divs Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Have weird problem with something I'm working on.

For reference here is the code: [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/SQ7BC/3/)

Just a recap of the flow:

1. Document is loaded, and there are two paragraphs of text.
2. jQuery is run, which is used to put every letter into a span--with a unique class number.
3. Spans all have CSS opacity transitions on them.
4. jQuery loops through all spans in #main container and adds .change class to trigger opacity. this loop ends once all spans have had the class added.

Now the thing I'm missing, is a way to loop through all the divs in the span--and randomly start to change the opacity on each span to 0. This needs to be done in a completely random order--but needs to stop once all spans have been looped through.

I have some code for the math below--but I'm not exactly sure why its not working.

```
var min = 1;
var max = 400;
var paras = $('#main span');
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
paras.hasClass('number' + random).addClass('change');
```

Can anyone assist me with the math--or help me come up with another solution, I'm sure the effect will look great if its working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always select only the remaining `span` element without the `change` class.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/SQ7BC/10/)

```
function randomChange() {
    var paras = $('#main span:not(.change)');
    var min = 0;
    var max = paras.length - 1;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    $(paras.get(random)).addClass('change');

    if (paras.length > 1) setTimeout(randomChange, 5);
}
```

---

We can make it more efficient if we search for the unchanged spans only once and remove the changed items from the array.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/SQ7BC/14/)

```
var paras = $('#main span:not(.change)');

function randomChange() {
    var min = 0;
    var max = paras.length - 1;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    $(paras.get(random)).addClass('change');

    // Remove from item from the array
    paras.splice(random, 1);

    console.log("Chose: "+ random + " Out: " + max);
    if (paras.length > 0) setTimeout(randomChange, 5);
}
```

Comment: Awesome--love the way you're creating a single loop for all spans. I had a pure jQuery solution i didnt post that spiked my CPU to 99%...using this CSS method I'm seeing low 30%'s...great!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

.hasClass isn't a selector, you need to select the span elements you want to change:

`$('#main span.number'+random).addClass("change");`

Answer (score 0):

You might be over-engineering it. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQ7BC/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').each(function(){        
        var spans = $(this).text().split(' ');        
        $p = $("<p></p>");        
        $.each(spans, function(index, value) {
          $p.append($("<span>"+value+" </span>"));
        });        
        $(this).replaceWith($p);        
    });

    $("#main span").each(function(index) {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
        $(this).delay(r).fadeTo('slow', 0);
    });    
});
```